# How to retrieve all versions of a document using SQL queries in Filenet P8?

Tags: sql, filenet-p8, filenet, filenet-content-engine

I'm looking for a way to retry and if needed remove all documents located inside the tree of a given folder root with all of their versions, not just the current one.

The easiest way might be a SQL query with a batch deletion. Since previous version of a document are not filed in a Folder, I proceeded to do it this way:

- Perform a `SELECT` request on Document class
- Add a `LEFT JOIN` between a document version (`Document AS doc`) and other versions (`Document AS doc2`) using version_series key.
- Filter to get only current version from other versions (`doc2.IsCurrentVersion = true`)
- Filder to get only documents whose current version is filed in a given Folder tree (`INSUBFOLDER clause`)

Additional step:

- Left joins with `ReferentialContainmentRelationShip` and `Folder` classes to get the path name of the folder of the document current version

The final request looks like below:

```
SELECT doc.this,
       doc.majorversionnumber AS "MAJV",
       doc.minorversionnumber AS "MINV",
       doc.IsCurrentVersion AS "Is Current",
       doc2.This AS "Current version",
       f.pathname AS "Current version folder"
FROM ((Document doc
       LEFT JOIN Document doc2 ON
                 doc2.VersionSeries = doc.VersionSeries)
       LEFT JOIN ReferentialContainmentRelationShip rcr ON
                 doc2.VersionSeries = rcr.VersionSeries)
LEFT JOIN Folder f ON f.This = rcr.tail
WHERE doc2.IsCurrentVersion = true AND
      doc2.this INSUBFOLDER '/path/to/a/folder'
ORDER BY doc2.This
```

Is this a good and not overkill way to achieve what the goal?

Answer (score 0):

Deleting a document will remove all versions.  You would have to do a Demote to just remove the Current Version.